# Is it possible to find all subdomains for a certain domain?

Tags: domains, dns, subdomain

a client of mine is currently hosting a web-project on one of his servers with some sub domains for previews, testing etc.

Those are really hard to guess sub domains like:

- `donottestme123789.example.com`
- `preview_for_you15685485468.example.com`

and so on ...

In the past days we noticed, that there are some users using those project instances which shouldn't even know of those :-)

Is there any way besides Google or brute forcing to get a full listing of sub domains from a domain?

Comment: Do you really mean for an entire **top level** domain?  That means .com, .org, .net, .uk etc.  Do you really mean for a **domain** such as example.com?

Comment: I meant a domain - sorry - edited the question ...

Comment: @Christofian - no site:*.sitename.com will not work. Google does not allow wildcards in site search anymore.

Comment: I liked one answer from this forum - [link](https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/how-to-find-subdomains-of-a-domain.251504/) . Searching for site:sitename.com -inurl:www gives all the sub-domains that are indexed by Search Engines.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, there's no way other than bruteforcing.

And if you try that, you'll likely find yourself blacklisted.

Answer (score 7):

Try this brute force script in Linux:
It uses [reverse DNS lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) (one name per IP), so it can't find virtual hosts (when at one IP more then one name).

```
vi /tmp/dnsscan.sh
```

Type **i** and paste this:

```
#!/bin/bash
IPPFX=$1
for i in `seq 1 255` ; do LIST="$LIST ${IPPFX}.$i" ; done
for i in $LIST ; do
    ENTRY="`host $i`"
    [ $? -ne 0 ] && continue
    ENTRY=`echo "$ENTRY" l sed -e 's/.* //' -e 's/\.$//'`
    echo -e "$i\t$ENTRY"
done
```

Then type **[Esc]:wq** and run

```
chmod 777 /tmp/dnsscan.sh
```

Then:

```
/tmp/dnsscan.sh your.ipv4.address
```

Replace ***your.ipv4.address*** with **IPv4** *without last octet!*

For example *http://www.wikipedia.org* have next IP address: **208.80.152**.201, so you need execute this:

```
/tmp/dnsscan.sh 208.80.152
```

Result will be:

```
208.80.152.1    vrrp-gw-100.wikimedia.org
208.80.152.2    rr.pmtpa.wikimedia.org
208.80.152.3    upload.pmtpa.wikimedia.org
208.80.152.5    m.pmtpa.wikimedia.org
208.80.152.6    owa.wikimedia.org
208.80.152.7    payments.wikimedia.org
208.80.152.10   lvs-svc-test.wikimedia.org
... so on
```

If you need to find virtual hosts try Bing.com with *real* **IP:**

Example: `http://www.bing.com/search?q=**IP:208.80.152.201`

Answer (score 6):

Your client should have access and in some way control on the nameservers, that are authoritative for his domains.

Why not asking the DNS admin for a zone download/export?

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget that if you use another website after using the test website, the test website's URL will likely show up in the other site's referrer log, which can lead to the admin of the other site knowing that yours exists.

Comment: That shouldn't happen unless you click a link to that other website (in which case the page containing the backlink would be the referrer). Otherwise that would be a huge invasion of privacy.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to click on a link for that, loading any external content (an image for example) on the test website will show up as a referrer on the external server.

Comment: @arjaj: That's technically correct, and it's used for a lot of analytics applications. But I was referring to the act of the user visiting a webpage as the answer discusses. gbroiles' answer seems to suggest that simply using the same browser window/tab to visit another site will cause the current site's URL to be logged as a referrer. But that is simply not the case unless you arrive at the new site via a link (or redirect).

Answer (score 1):

If the hoster of your domain did not configure the nameservers properly, an AXFR transfer could list all the subdomains in your zone. I've seen hosting setups where AXFR to the outside world is denied (good), but it allowed an AXFR lookup for their hosted domains, from within their network, so anyone with a server or VPS could get such a list for any domain host

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you google `site:*.sitename.com`, google will wildcard the `*`, and display a list of sub domains.

Answer (score 0):

He who has access to the DNS zone files (or "control panel") can give you the complete list of subdomains. If the name servers that service the domain name allow for an [AXFR transfer](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch2/index.html#axfr-update) (or if the DNS manager allows that for you and your IP address) you can transfer copies of the zone locally and find the list yourself.

And there is always the case of a [wildcard](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/apd/rfc4592.txt) in the zone declaration, in which case any subdomain is a valid one...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to plesk for their hosting, in there you could look under the subdomains tab of the main domain